# using TF to install ops-agent fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ops-agent

so using tf this command is generated..

`gcloud beta compute instances ops-agents policies create ops-agents-policy-centos-7 --agent-rules=enable-autoupgrade=true,package-state=installed,type=ops-agent,version=current-major --group-labels=jvr=jvr --os-types=short-name=centos,version=7 --project=my-project --quiet`

the agent is never installed and I am seeing this in the logs..

`Error performing yum changes: error installing yum packages: error running /usr/bin/yum with args ["install" "--assumeyes" "stackdriver-agent" "stackdriver-agent-start-service" "google-fluentd-catch-all-config" "google-fluentd-start-service" "google-fluentd" "google-cloud-ops-agent"]: exit status 1, stdout: "Loaded plugins: fastestmirror\nDetermining fastest mirrors\n * base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com\n * epel: forksystems.mm.fcix.net\n * extras: mirror.datto.com\n * updates: mirror.wdc2.us.leaseweb.net\nResolving Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package google-cloud-ops-agent.x86_64 0:2.34.0-1.el7 will be installed\n---> Package google-fluentd.x86_64 0:1.10.1-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-core for package: google-fluentd-1.10.1-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package google-fluentd-catch-all-config.noarch 0:0.8.0-1 will be installed\n---> Package google-fluentd-start-service.noarch 0:0.0.1-1 will be installed\n---> Package stackdriver-agent.x86_64 0:6.3.1-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: yajl for package: stackdriver-agent-6.3.1-1.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libyajl.so.2()(64bit) for package: stackdriver-agent-6.3.1-1.el7.x86_64\n---> Package stackdriver-agent-start-service.noarch 0:0.0.1-1 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package redhat-lsb-core.x86_64 0:4.1-27.el7.centos.1 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb-submod-security(x86-64) = 4.1-27.el7.centos.1 for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: spax for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/fuser for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/time for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/patch for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/make for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/m4 for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/lpr for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/lp for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/killall for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/batch for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/at for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /bin/mailx for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: /bin/ed for package: redhat-lsb-core-4.1-27.el7.centos.1.x86_64\n---> Package yajl.x86_64 0:2.0.4-4.el7 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package at.x86_64 0:3.1.13-25.el7_9 will be installed\n---> Package cups-client.x86_64 1:1.6.3-51.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: cups-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.6.3-51.el7 for package: 1:cups-client-1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libcups.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-client-1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-common.so.3()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-client-1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency: libavahi-client.so.3()(64bit) for package: 1:cups-client-1.6.3-51.el7.x86_64\n---> Package ed.x86_64 0:1.9-4.el7 will be installed\n---> Package m4.x86_64 0:1.4.16-10.el7 will be installed\n---> Package mailx.x86_64 0:12.5-19.el7 will be installed\n---> Package make.x86_64 1:3.82-24.el7 will be installed\n---> Package patch.x86_64 0:2.7.1-12.el7_7 will be installed\n---> Package psmisc.x86_64 0:22.20-17.el7 will be installed\n---> Package redhat-lsb-submod-security.x86_64 0:4.1-27.el7.centos.1 will be installed\n---> Package spax.x86_64 0:1.5.2-13.el7 will be installed\n---> Package time.x86_64 0:1.7-45.el7 will be installed\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package avahi-libs.x86_64 0:0.6.31-20.el7 will be installed\n---> Package cups-libs.x86_64 1:1.6.3-51.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Conflict: google-cloud-ops-agent-2.34.0-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts stackdriver-agent\n--> Processing Conflict: google-cloud-ops-agent-2.34.0-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts google-fluentd\n--> Finished Dependency Resolution\n You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem\n You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest\n", stderr: "Error: google-cloud-ops-agent conflicts with google-fluentd-1.10.1-1.el7.x86_64\nError: google-cloud-ops-agent conflicts with stackdriver-agent-6.3.1-1.el7.x86_64\n"`

why is it attempting to install all of those when all it needs is google-cloud-ops-agent?
I am assuming it's something in the black box that is doing it.. but I can't figure out where the gcloud command is turned into the yum install command that is including all the old agents that are not being requested.

Oh and this is being applied to a fresh centos 7 VM that does not have any of the agents installed.

AND when I do it with the on client installation it works..  so this is some where between gcloud and it's pre-made script for installing..

Comment: Invest the time to format your question correctly. It is very hard to read `BIG BLOBS OF TEXT`. Also, replace `\n` characters with line breaks so that lines are broken correctly.

Comment: thank you for the advice.  but do you have anything that pertains to the question?

Answer (score -1):

/Something/ was fixed.  suddenly it works with out me changing any code.